# How to add a click event to Tile in FLP plugin?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to add click event to all the tiles in the launchpad without changing any code inside tile. For that I am creating a FLP plugin.
To attach press event to tile I tried to get the tiles using the following code:

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("LaunchPage").getGroups().then(function(aGroups) {
                for (var i = 0; i < aGroups.length; i++) {
                    var aTiles = sap.ushell.Container.getService("LaunchPage").getGroupTiles(aGroups[i]);
                    for (var j = 0; j < aTiles.length; j++) {
                    aTiles[j].getImplementationAsSapui5().getTileControl().attachPress(function(oEvent) {
                                console.log("Tile clicked")
                            });
                        }
                }
            });
```

There is no error but it does not show "Tile Clicked" on click of any tile. If I get the tiles using the following code, it works fine:

```
    var aTiles = sap.ushell.utils.getVisibleTiles();
            for (var j = 0; j < aTiles.length; j++) {
                aTiles[j].attachPress(function(oEvent) {
                    console.log(oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getObject().object.getTitle());
                });
            }
```

The issue is that it only returns visible tiles on the screen.

Can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by attaching hash change event. I am getting all tile names and hash values using launchPage service and then using that on hash change to match the hash value to get the title. Even if the tile is opened directly using the url the event will be captured.

```
sap.ushell.Container.getService("LaunchPage").getGroups().then(function(aGroups) {
for (var i = 0; i < aGroups.length; i++) {
    var aGrpTiles = 
          sap.ushell.Container.getService("LaunchPage").getGroupTiles(aGroups[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < aGrpTiles.length; j++) {
        var sTileTitle = sap.ushell.Container.getService("LaunchPage").getTileTitle(aGrpTiles[j]);
        var sTileTarget = sap.ushell.Container.getService("LaunchPage").getCatalogTileTargetURL(aGrpTiles[j]);
        if (sTileTitle.indexOf("App Launcher") === 0) {
         sTileTitle = sTileTarget;
        }       
        window.UserTiles.push({
            title: sTileTitle,
            url: sTileTarget
        });
    }
  }
}.bind(this));

window.addEventListener("hashchange", this._onHashChange.bind(this), true);

_onHashChange: function(oEvent) {
    var sOldHash = this._getHashFromURL(oEvent.oldURL);
    var sNewHash = this._getHashFromURL(oEvent.newURL);
    //handled for the change of URL while navigation within the app
    if (sOldHash !== sNewHash) {
        console.log("new tile");
        var tile = window.UserTiles.filter(function(o) {
          if (o.url) {
            return sap.ushell.utils.getBasicHash(o.url).indexOf(sHash) === 0;
          }
       });
       console.log("tile title:" + tile[0].title, "tile hash:"+ tile.url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will use your code and if I could give you some info, I will reply again.

I give you two ideas for posible workarrounds to your doubt:

- In my case, for do some custom actions with home tiles, I have created a Custom Tile Type, maybe you could consider it.
- Other solution that I have created for send Google Analytics navigation events was to create a SAPUI5 plugin for handling Hash changes. Then I know where I am and where I want to go.

Regards

Comment: If I use hash change it will be triggered even when navigation happens within the application. And in this case how will I get the tile title from hash value?

Comment: In my case, I am using a variable in sapui5 plugin for checking some behaviour. Furthermore, for me the hash was better that title because the SAP FLP is multilanguage and for do some statistics the hash is the same in spanish, english, etc

Comment: ahh I see the advantage of using hash. Is there a way to find out the group from where the tile is clicked for the cases when tile is present in multiple groups.

Comment: yes, I hope that another point of view helps you to find a solution.